# Why am I not getting an html object from fetch()?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Hi,

I have this code:

```
var files = [];

  fetch('https://example.org/files/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then((html) => {
    files = html.querySelectorAll("td > a");
    
    files.forEach(elm =>
     files.push(elm);
    );
```

this is the source of the URL to be fetched:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /files</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /files</h1>
  <table>
   <tr><th valign="top">&nbsp;</th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="/files/">Parent Directory</a>       </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="a1.gif">a1.gif</a>                 </td><td align="right">2022-05-06 21:33  </td><td align="right">362 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="a2.gif">a2.gif</a>                 </td><td align="right">2022-05-06 21:34  </td><td align="right">426 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top">&nbsp;</td><td><a href="a3.gif">a3.gif</a>                 </td><td align="right">2022-05-06 21:34  </td><td align="right">451 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

so fetch should output the following:

```
["/files/", "a1.gif", "a2.gif", "a3.gif"]
```

the URL is fetched but I get no values from it. Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: Plain text does not have methods like `querySelectorAll()`. You need to parse the HTML string into a document

Comment: use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: thank you. I knew I had to parse it but I didnt know how.